# How to create a DbCommand that is compatible with SQL Server and SQLite without a large condition?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlite

HI lets say I have a C# code

```
private const string INSERT = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";

public static DbCommand INSERTCOMMAND(IPerson person)
{
    DbCommand command = null;
    var sqlParams = new List<DbParameter>();

    if(SQLManagerFactory.SQLManager is SQLServerManager)
    {
        command = new SqlCommand(INSERT);
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", person.FirstName);
        sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", person.LastName);
    }
    else // SQLiteManager
    {
        command = new SQLiteCommand(INSERT);
        sqlParams.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FirstName", person.FirstName);
        sqlParams.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@LastName", person.LastName);
    }

    command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
    return command;
}
```

Which is working perfectly fine. Of course in my production code, it is quite bigger and has a lot more location that does the similar things for different commands.

My question is that is there way to make this shorter? I do not wish to copy and paste code which essentially does the same thing except for calling the different constructors.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: i don't know much about SQL Lite but make a procedure separately and call them

Comment: create a custom class that handles the passing of params and loops for the count

Comment: Use a Facade pattern over your InsertCommand and/or wrap the Parameter Creation to someting like (CreateParam) and check it there.

Comment: Using one of the many ORM-DAO wrappers can simplify writing such cross-vendor code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be fine, I'm leaving out details but you can figure those out:

```
private const string INSERT = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";

public static DbCommand INSERTCOMMAND(IPerson person)
{
    DbCommand command = null;
    var sqlParams = new List<DbParameter>();
    MySqlEnum sqlType = SQLManagerFactory.SQLManager is SQLServerManager ? MySqlEnum.SQLServer : MySqlEnum.sqlLite

    if(sqlType == MySqlEnum.SQLServer)
        command = new SqlCommand(INSERT);
    else // SQLiteManager
        command = new SQLiteCommand(INSERT);

    sqlParams.Add(new CustomSqlParameter(sqlType ,"@FirstName", person.FirstName);
    sqlParams.Add(new CustomSqlParameter(sqlType ,"@LastName", person.LastName);

    command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
    return command;
}
```

The code for CustomSqlParameter should be obvious

Comment: @user2864740 - You have to write it -- you look at the first parameter and return the correct result.

Comment: @user2864740 - bad name... let me fix that.

Comment: @user2864740 -- there, I changed `MySqlParameter` to `CustomSqlParameter` -- while `MySqlParameter` is not a name that is include in the C# libraries I can see how you would get confused.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of design and testability I think it isn't right to couple things as in your example.

Imagine that something change only for one database, and you need to change INSERT query, this would cause problem because the same query is used for other database.

Actually, you could create `PersonRepository` abstraction:

```cs
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    void Add(IPerson person)
}
```

and create two implementations of that interface :

```cs
public SqlServerPersonRepository : IPersonRepository 
{
    void Add(IPerson person)
    {
        //sql server specific code
    }
}

public SqlLitePersonRepository : IPersonRepository 
{
    void Add(IPerson person)
    {
        //sqlite specific code
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the content of the database (both SQL and SQLite) are going to be synced. so for that purpose, I would not want to have separate implementation of each repository.

Comment: It's up to you but probably this would burden your data access with if-else statements. The conditions will be everywhere spreading all your data acess code. 
In @Hogan approach even if the parameters are added the same way for SqlServer and SQLite, I think there will be situations that this is not possible, for example for `DateTime`. And this generate more conditions.

Comment: I agree with this approach.  However, I would create an "public abstract class PersonBaseRepository" that each of the conretes above implement.  Then the "shared" code can go in the Base class.  But this is a better idea...get RID of the if/else statements and use OO

Answer (score 0):

Move the database-specific knowledge into the `SQLManager` class (or create your own classes that wrap it):

```
public static DbCommand INSERTCOMMAND(IPerson person)
{
    var sqlParams = new List<DbParameter>();
    var sql = SQLManagerFactory.SQLManager; // or MyOwnSQLManager

    var command = sql.CreateCommand(INSERT);
    sqlParams.Add(sql.CreateParameter("@FirstName", person.FirstName));
    sqlParams.Add(sql.CreateParameter("@LastName", person.LastName));

    command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
    return command;
}
```